# Рецепт популяризации сайта

Tags: обсуждение

<sub>Примечание. В блоге компании была опубликована [крайне интересная статья](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/) от [@Robert Cartaino](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/rcartaino/). Как мне кажется, она будет интересна участникам сообщества.</sub>

---

В статье «[7 главных мета-вопросов каждой беты](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)»  были описаны ключевые шаги формирования жизнеспособного сообщества вопросов и ответов сети [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/). Сегодня мы попытаемся предложить вам как наши личные советы, так и советы участников сообщества, о том, **каким образом продвигать ваш сайт**.

### Делитесь качественными вопросами и ответами

Лучший и простейший способ продвижения сайта – **делиться ссылками на по-настоящему хорошие вопросы и ответы**. Отличительная черта, краеугольный камень и фундамент Stack Exchange – вопросы и ответы, которыми можно гордиться и делиться с миром. Рискую показаться банальным, но ссылку на вопрос можно получить следующими способами:

- Скопировать URL из адресной строку вашего обозревателя.
- Правой клавишей мыши щелкнуть на названии вопроса (ссылка на вопрос) и нажать «копировать».
- Правой клавишей мыши щелкнуть на надписи «поделиться», расположенной под вопросом или ответом и нажать «копировать».

Если вам нужен сокращенный URL – потребуется только идентификатор вопроса. Например, если имеется:

```
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1811/hello-world-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-main
```

URL можно сократить до:

```
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1811/
```

или

```
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1811/
```

Сокращенный URL можно скопировать из меню по ссылке «поделиться», расположенной под каждым вопросом и ответом. Из этого же меню вы можете поделиться вопросом в Google+, Facebook или Twitter.

### Большой путь преодолевается маленькими шагами

Неужели возможно популяризировать сайт просто делясь ссылкой на вопросы? – спросите вы. Мы не знаем наверняка! Но мы знаем, что чтобы ответить на масштабные вопросы, такие как «Как популяризировать сайт?», следует начинать с малого – задать менее глобальные, конкретные вопросы, на которые легче ответить, к примеру:

- Каковы три крупнейшие конференции для разработчиков, которые мы могли бы спонсировать?
- Может ли сообщество спонсировать локальные встречи разработчиков, или проводить свои Stack Overflow–собрания посвященные программированию?
- В каких 10 лучших подкастах про программирование можно рассказать про сообщество?

Не останавливайтесь на этом. После того, как вы получите первый «урожай»  ответов на подобные вопросы, используйте их, чтобы задать еще более детальные вопросы.

- Кто-нибудь знаком с ведущим подкаста, чтобы попросить его записать эпизод с участниками сообщества или рассказать о сайте своим подписчикам в Twitter?

Процесс требует большей организованности и дисциплины, чем в случае, когда вы задаете только один вопрос, а потом пассивно ожидаете от него отдачи. Чтобы добиться какого–либо результата, необходимо, чтобы участники сообщества проявили инициативу и задавали вопросы методично, стратегически, целенаправленно.

### Компания, со своей стороны, поддержит начинания

Любое сообщество, приложившее достаточные усилия и применившее нестандартные идеи к популяризации своего сайта, получит бюджет и ресурсы, необходимые для реализации этих идей. Финансирование будет соответствовать объему усилий, инноваций, ресурсов, идей, вложенных сообществом. Самое главное условие – *сообщество должно быть источником вышеперечисленных идей* – ведь именно вы, а не компания, обладаете экспертизой в вашей предметной области!

Соответствие бюджета и приложенных усилий гарантирует, что:

- Получатели финансирования заинтересованы в развитии сайта.
- Сообщество осознает, что усилия участников не пропадают даром и это помогает им улучшать сайт.

В качестве примера, предлагаем вам несколько идей по развитию сайтов:

- Предлагайте компании спонсорскую поддержку стратегически важных для сообщества конференций. В этой связи вполне можно выделить 2-3 лучшие конференции.
- Связывайтесь с нужными блоггерами и журналистами. Сделайте так, чтобы ключевые эксперты программирования знали о сайте – и не только «тысячники»: следует общаться с обычными разработчиками, которые действительно посещают эти конференции.
- Предлагайте компании спонсорскую поддержку развлекательных акций сообщества.. особенно тех, которые, скорее всего, будут бурно обсуждаться.
- Убедитесь, что евангелисты сообщества имеют возможность выступить перед экспертами. Возможно, стоит создать «бюро докладчиков», которое будет заниматься бронированием мест на конференциях, дискуссионных клубах и т.д. для лучших участников сообщества, которые могли бы рассказать на них про сообщество.
- По возможности, поднимайте вопрос о сайте на встречах, конференциях и дискуссионных группах, которые посещаете лично вы, если тема соответствует контексту существующего диалога.
- В случае проведения интересных конкурсов и акций компания будет рада предоставить доступ к услугам профессиональных дизайнеров и к подарочной продукции (футболкам, наклейкам и т.д.).

Примеры выше нужны, чтобы подтолкнуть вас подумать: «Что бы предпринять, чтобы поднять наш сайт на мировой уровень?». Не ждите наших подсказок. Именно вам предстоит запустить этот механизм. И хотя глас вопиющего в пустыне в некоторых типах сотрудничества/мозгового штурма оказывается эффективным, иногда именно участники (да–да именно вы!) должны взять на себя роль организатора.

Со своей стороны, мы бы хотели дать только два ключевых совета:

- Поощряйте сообщество делиться ссылками на качественные вопросы и ответы. Если вы чувствуете, что сообщество не успевает создавать качественные вопросы и ответы, достойные того, чтобы поделиться ими с миром, сначала решите эту задачу.
- Что касается продвижения, не пытайтесь объять необъятное. Если идеи по продвижению грандиозны, они ошибочны. Разбейте их на более мелкие, более специфичные, чтобы каждый участник сообщества мог поучаствовать и помочь в их осуществлении.

Если в большой компании друзей вы спросите «Какие у нас планы на ужин?», вы столкнетесь с нерешительностью и пассивностью. Но если ваш вопрос будет более конкретен: «Где тут можно заказать хорошую пиццу?», в течение получаса вы уже будете ее есть (или же она достанется вам бесплатно).

---

Если у вас есть ваша личная стратегия популяризации сообщества, пожалуйста, поделитесь ей в ответах на этот вопрос!

Comment: Как-то... масло масляное. Известности SO уже не занимать, на мой взгляд. Если я напишу завлекательный текст и захочу разбросать копии с самолёта, чтобы каждая домохозяйка получила брошюрку, то даст ли мне SE самолёт на это благое дело?

Comment: @Other Если каждая домохозяйка знает программирование, то будьте уверены, что даст.

Comment: @Other Stack Overflow, как бы странно это не звучало, крайне мало известен за пределами англоязычного мира. Чтобы показать масштаб бедствия, приведу простой пример: на SOen более 12м вопросов, а посещаемость среди русскоязычной аудитории в 4 раза меньше чем у CyberForum. Если взять в расчет качество содержимого, то ситуация выглядит просто абсурдно.

Comment: Ага, я недавно у первокурсников факультета информационных технологий спрашивал, знают ли они про SO. Очень мало знают )

Comment: Не знаю статистики, не буду спорить. Хотя в моём окружении знаю о SO все. Тогда не нужно домохозяек, сброс листовок над универами, организации конференций, реклама на ТВ (не та аудитория, но зато без AdBlock'а). Идей масса, чего их не реализуют? Или потому, что Вы - единственный менеджер по ruSO и Вам рук не хватает?

Comment: @Other Идеи должны исходить от участников сообщества! Я, как участник сообщества, конечно же предлагаю некоторые активности (например, во времена ХэшКода мы действительно раздавали листовки перед петербургским офисом Яндекса), но настоящие развитие возможно только если и другие участники будут что–либо предпринимать.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Идей много, проблема в реализации. Почему бы компании не закупить N тыс. наклеек/брелков и не высылать партии активистам, чтобы раздавали их знакомым/желающим/любым? В ресурсы (материалы, деньги, время, возможности, т. д.) упирается вопрос, а участия участников найти можно, при желании. А я не слышал чтобы компания давала возможности.

Comment: @Other Потому что никто не предлагал! Выслать наклейки/ручки/брелки – не проблема!

Comment: "Никто не предлагал" - что именно? Помощь? Тогда тут же, на мете, кинули клич, собрали добровольцев и начали работу.

Comment: @Other Ага! Это он и есть! :)

Comment: Я тут не увидел призыва вида "Ребята, давайте жить помогая! Предложения, реквизиты для отправки брелков, etc!". Только "Давайте активнее продвигать, ну что же вы!".

Comment: @Other Буду признателен, если вы опубликуете вопрос в правильном формате, сославшись на этот вопрос, при необходимости. Было бы здорово собрать различные идеи по видению развития сообщества в одном месте.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас посмотрю как правильно его преподнести.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4080

Comment: @Other Большое спасибо!

Comment: Всегда рад помочь!

Answer (score 6):

Почему-то никто не задает себе одного очень простого вопроса. А я его задам: почему компания делает акцент только на количестве аудитории, но не на ее качестве?

С точки зрения бизнеса - это более-менее оправдано, ведь именно трафик (в конечном счете) влияет на уровень дохода.

А вот с точки зрения сообщества привлечение большого количества новичков-школьников является **сомнительным благом**. Такие новички, в большинстве своем, бесполезны для накопления знаний: в 99% случаев они задают по одному низкокачественному вопросу и получив (или даже не получив) ответа уходят навсегда. Иногда все еще хуже: они дублируют свои низкокачественные вопросы, не получив ответ. Кроме этого, они не дают качественных ответов сами и даже не в состоянии задать нормальный вопрос.

Ситуация дополнительно осложняется тем фактом, что новички в глазах компании по-определению более ценный ресурс. Модераторы (не буду тыкать пальцем) почему-то считают их "**священными коровами**" и всячески их оберегают, не дай бог они уйдут с сайта. Причем даже в ущерб интересам/принципам/идеологии/whatever "старичков".

Вместе с тем, людей, которые регулярно отвечают на вопросы средней и высокой сложности не так уж и много. И это делает ru.SO относительно бесполезным для профессиональных разработчиков: часто найти ответ самому намного проще/быстрее, чем публиковать вопрос и ждать.

Так может быть правильнее делать акцент не на "*популяризации сайта*", а на превращение его в место, где действительно можно **получить ответ на вопрос** хоть чуточку сложнее чем "*где ошибка в моем коде*"?!

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, на чем основано допущение что новые участники сообщества это обязательно новички–первоклашки? Каждый из топ-10 участников, когда–то получил свои первые 10 баллов репутации.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, посмотрите на распределение репутации у участников сообщества. Большая часть имеет всего 1 бал репутации.

Comment: `на превращение его в место, где действительно можно получить ответ на вопрос ` Как мы видим, сложность в том, чтобы публиковались такие вопросы. Задача инициативы привлечь людей, которые их будут задавать! К сожалению, из общения с коллегами, я вижу следующие: люди задают свои вопросы лично (либо в реальной жизни, либо через сообщения в соц сетях).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну и как я уже не раз говорил, проблема не в привлечении аудитории в принципе, а в привлечении людей, способных внести положительный вклад  в процесс обмена знаниями

Comment: Да, 1 балл. Репутация означает: 1) вклад в развитие сообщества, 2) знание системы. Репутация != знания, хотя, в большинстве случаев существует значительная положительная корреляция.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, "_К сожалению, из общения с коллегами, я вижу следующие: люди задают свои вопросы лично_" - разумеется, потому что на ru.SO сложно получить качественный ответ на вопрос. **Быстрее и проще** спросить IRL либо решить проблему самому.

Comment: Мы говорим о популяризации сообщества среди профессиональных разработчиков, а не школьников, хотя в [толковых школьниках](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1267/), лично я ничего плохого не вижу.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "_Репутация != знания_" - а сколько (в процентах) пользователей задало всего один вопрос? Еще раз: я говорю не только о знаниях, но и о качестве аудитории. Школьники с опечатками в подключении жиквери плюгинамов  - бесполезны для сообщества.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48651/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-nicolas-chabanovsky).

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, почему новая аудитория должна быть школьниками, а не хорошими разработчиками?

Answer (score 2):

> Процесс требует большей организованности и дисциплины, чем в случае,
>   когда вы задаете только один вопрос, а потом пассивно ожидаете от него
>   отдачи.

Организованность и дисциплина это скорее из разряда, когда кто-то кому-нибудь и что-нибудь должен. Вряд ли это соответствует идее свободного дележа информацией, так сказать, по доброте душевной. С этим несомненно согласится большинство (считающих себя должниками попрошу текст далее не читать, у вас всё хорошо). А далее по тексту: пассивно ждём отдачи. Упс... И здесь опять кто-то кому-то и отчего-то должен. Этот кому-то пребывает в мыслях (разумеется, на людях такое не брякнешь), что является представителем этакой местной ОКГ (организованная кредиторская группа) и может, если что, и предъявить в том случае, если ожидание нежданно затянется.

Конечно, кредиторами в миг не становятся, но по праву затраченных (быть может, всуе, а быть может и нет) человеко-часов, начинают причислять себя, если и не к избранным, то уж к свидетелям какого-либо дня недели точно. И поначалу вскользь упоминать, затем просить, чуть позже - ныть, и, как апогей эволюции, требовать, чтобы ответка за ранее опрометчиво розданные блага всё же накрыла. Но... её всё нет и нет. И тогда пылкий Мальчиш, что так весело и с упоением проводил ликбез, медленно превращается из того самого Кибальчиша... правильно, в Плохиша, сама суть претензий которого ограничивается лишь тем, чтобы выгодно было. Этот карьерный рост со временем всё более даёт о себе знать, и вот уже на горизонте маячат лавры Главного Буржуина... Но не будем о грустном для тех, кто ещё не успел или вообще едет в другом вагоне.

> Чтобы добиться какого–либо результата, необходимо, чтобы
>   участники сообщества проявили инициативу и задавали вопросы методично,
>   стратегически, целенаправленно.

Как когда-то известное сочинение получило низкую оценку за недостаточностью раскрытия темы ухода из жизни, так и здесь не говорится о том, какие цифры соответствуют той популяризации, что в конечном итоге и должна явиться тем самым загадочным результатом. Однозначно можно утверждать, что день, месяц, год и более назад сайт был менее популярен, нежели чем сегодня. Тогда в чём вопрос, и отчего раз за разом возникают посты, если и не уровня путин-слил, то как минимум с набором из различных пожеланий и советов трудящимся, как те могут скрасить свой досуг, превратив его в увлекательный квест взятия высот пятилетки?

Мотивация, конечно, нужна. Но с другой стороны, если она становится всё более нужна или требует поддержки брелками, значит что-то идёт не так? Или запал растрачен, или, быть может, растрачен впустую, и неоткуда ему взяться вновь? Не уверен, что лично я верю в это.

Чем мне нравятся вновь прибывшие, так это тем, что они понятия не имеют о существовании местных позывов к мотивации. От слова совсем. У них есть вполне конкретная задача - получить ответ на свой вопрос. Некоторые из них, удовлетворившись ответами, входят во вкус и сами начинают со временем отвечать. Заметьте, это никоим образом не зависит от их уровня знаний. Но всё это длится ровно до тех пор, пока не начинается уже упомянутый мною ранее карьерный рост. Пусть и не в Плохиша, а просто потому, что однообразно, скучно и некуда расти. Даже придумали гольф, этакое развлечение, несущее мало практической пользы (потому как редко оно кому по жизни надо), но хотя бы позволяющее показать ближнему своему, что уж с меня-то песок ещё не весь вышел.

Но может вся проблема лишь и заключается в том, что попросту утратили интерес от самого процесса добавления вопроса? Почему бы не добавить пару-тройку на интересующую тему, интересующего уровня? Может быть подключатся к процессу и другие. Вернётся общение, а с ним и былой интерес. Кто осмелится утверждать, что он знает всё и ему нечего спрашивать, тот Главный Буржуин и в Буржуинство ему дорога, а кто всё же сомневается, тот молодец.