# Меры для популяризации SO на русском

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Приветствую.
Вопрос "[Рецепт популяризации сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4072)" поднял интересный факт:
Мало кто из русскоговорящих людей знает о SO и, конечно, о его сателлите "SO на русском".

Это печально, но поправимо, если сообщество не останется равнодушным и попытается сделать что-либо.

Предлагаю обсудить тут возможные варианты/идеи, направленные на популяризацию и развитие SO на русском, предложить свои услуги, устроить, так сказать, мозговой штурм.
Про возможность помощи вида "расшарьте ссылки" можете почитать в вопросе выше, там же написано что компания поддержит и/или профинансирует достойные идеи.

К примеру:

- Создать N наклеек, брелков, ручек, прочих сувениров, разослать желающим/имеющим возможности их раздать.
- Вы преподаватель программирования на C++? Отлично, запросите именные наклейки группы с призывом обращаться на SO от обладателей золотого знака по плюсам.
- Есть возможность выбить полёт с рекламными целями над универом неподалёку? Обратитесь за флаерами и самолётом к @NicolasChabanovsky, он сказал что [компания выделит ресурсы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4072/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0?noredirect=1#comment13382_4072) :)
- И так далее.

Потому что никто кроме нас.
Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: *"Мало кто из русскоговорящих людей знает о SO"* -- что это означает?  Сколько сейчас знают и сколько желательно чтобы знало? Что хочется увеличить: количество просмотров существующих вопросов? количество новых вопросов? количество людей, которые больше 5 сообщений в месяц на сайте пишут? ([cейчас ~400](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/391011/monthly-active-users-in-stackoverflow-stackexchange)) Какой критерий успеха? Какая сейчас ситуация? Какие цифры можно назвать хорошими, а какие просто превосходными через полгода? К примеру, [как ситуация изменилась за год](https://goo.gl/QzmTEV)

Comment: @jfs На сегодняшний день, я бы предложил использовать количество вопросов в день, как главный критерий активности сообщества, в сочетании со вторым параметром – процентом отвеченых вопросов. Вместе эти два численных показателя прекрасно описывают ситуацию на сайте, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky [ruSO уже в первую тройку по количеству вопросов попадает](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), имея наибольший процент отвеченных вопросов среди первой десятки сайтов, сортированных по количеству вопросов в день.

Comment: @jfs На мой взгляд, конечная цель Stack Overflow на русском – помочь русскоязычным разработчикам. Имея это в виду, я ориентируюсь на следующие показатели. 1. Процентное соотношение вопросов на SOen и SOru. В Интернете 5% русскоязычного трафика и 55% англоязычного. Распределение постов и трафика Википедии подтверждает эти цифры. 2. Соотношение SOru к старыми сайтами Рунета (а-ля CyberForum).

Comment: Просто хочу сказать, что, вот оставляю я вопросы, на них не отвечают на ru.stackoverflow.com, когда ставлю конкурс, один или 2 человека начинают пытаться помочь, это не всегда решение, часто - костыли. Даже сейчас у меня есть не решеные вопросы на страничке, которые давно пылятся. Сейчас я, как обычный пользователь этого сайта лучше перейду на оригинал версию, так как там есть решения ответов или там хотя бы есть те, кто всегда не ленится и помогает. Но здесь, на ru - сайте я просто, на авось, выкладываю вопросы, вдруг кто ответит. Ещё один плюс в том, что можно по русски вести беседу о коде

Comment: Многие знают о ru.stackoverflow.com, просто они им не часто им пользуются

Comment: @zayn1991: как раз статистика говорит обратное: у открытых вопросов больше шансов получить ответ на ruSO (84% против 72%--нажмите на ссылку выше). Конечно, если ваш вопрос попал в 1/6 часть неотвеченных, то вам не легче от того что на другом сайте, его шансы остаться неотвеченным почти в два раза больше.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: [согласно ссылке выше] отношение вопросов в день для SO/ruSO ~40, а просмотров ~200. Какие цифры хотелось бы увидеть вместо этого? Цифры в вашем комментарии не понял--можно конкретные ссылки. К примеру для статей в Википедия: [English (12.4%)   Russian (3.2%)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedias)

Comment: Насчёт процента отвеченных вопросов - тут есть лукавство: на обоих сайтах авторы вопросов часто не реагируют на ответы, даже правильные. На en.so они так и остаются без принятия и без плюсов. А на ru.so спустя несколько дней появляется одинокий плюсик. Я на 99% уверен, что это дело рук кого-то из модераторов (полагаю, Николаса).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не ясно, что вы пытаетесь высказать: что ответы на ruSO получают больше внимания? Или что плюсы по-вашему не заслужены, ответы бесполезны и более того модераторы знают это, но ставят плюсы чтобы статистику накрутить? Если последнее (абсурдно), то не стоит без доказательств подобные заявления делать—такие действия несут вред сайту—если вы думаете что такое происходит, то начните отдельное обсуждение (если вы  серьёзно к своему заявлению относитесь).

Comment: @jfs - Ответы полезны, плюсы заслужены, действие того модератора(ов) нормальны. Но статистика таким образом действительно накручена, имхо. Но, повторю ещё раз - это нормально. Просто статистику на en.so незачем улучшать, поэтому там никто этим специально не занимается. Обсуждать тут нечего, имхо.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: если ответы полезны, плюсы заслужены, действия модераторов нормальны, то есть система работает как рассчитано, то в чём "накрученность" проявляется? В том, что ответам на большом SO меньше внимания уделяется и поэтому меньше плюсов? Но вы думаете, что не смотря на отсутствие плюсов, качество ответов с нулём голосов там, не хуже качества ответов с положительными голосами на ruSO? То есть, по вашему, голосование никак качество ответа не сигнализирует, даже если мы статистику в целом рассматриваем (а не отдельные примеры)? Это громкое заявление, которое следует обосновать.

Comment: Просто оставлю коммент под самым популярным ответом - вот у меня дети пытаются с моей помощью приобщится к разработке - так вот они говорят, что лучше задать вопрос в самом помоишном форуме, чем у этих "дядек" - там они чувствуют себя среди своих - а это многое значит - отсюда и культура произрастает

Comment: @titov_andrei: на SO подростки могут с подростками общаться (или кто под них косит--"on the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog") если есть желание. К примеру, (судя по названию) [Teenage Tuesday в чате](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/85048/teenage-territory?tab=schedule). Хотя (сужу по себе подобным) будучи подростком, для решения программиских задач, мне было всё равно биологический возраст/пол/раса/местоположение на планете того, кто грамотный ответ по  теме даёт

Comment: @jfs Если предположить, что люди в языковой нише используют интернет примерно одинаково в сравнении с аналогичными людьми, говорящими на другом языке, то [SOru должен быть лишь в 10 раз меньше SOen](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5). Допуская, что SOen развит до предела, можно говорить о пределе для русскоязычного сообщества в [790 вопросов/день](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov К проценту принятых модераторы (на правах модераторов) не имеют никакого отношения. [Сразу после миграции участники сообщества, все вместе, активно удаляли плохие сообщения (голосовали против вопросов и ответов, чтобы система удалила их в будущем)](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1340/6).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вывод из всех упомянутых пока цифр не очевиден. Почему сегодняшнее число вопросов пиком не является или почему оно не может быть в 100 раз больше, а если может, то полезно ли к этому стремиться и достичь? Таблица сайтов SE показывает, что traffic и кол-во вопросов разные коэффициенты роста могут иметь. quantcast говорит, что устройства из России и Украины ~3% на Stack Overflow. Википедия ссылка выше  показывает что доля статей может заметно превышать свою относительную аудиторию. Отношение ответы/вопросы уже сейчас близко к единице. Больше вопросов by itself его не улучшат.

Comment: @jfs С большой вероятностью, во многом сделанные предположения ошибочны, но не имея цели никуда не прийдешь. С ростом количества вопросов, соотношение количества вопросов к ответам первое время всегда уменьшается, а потом возрастает. Я объясняю это двумя факторами: 1) необходимостью обучать правилам общения в сообществе новых участников; 2) все те, кто не может адаптироваться к новой модели ведения профессионального диалога покидают сообщество спустя какое–то время.

Comment: @jfs Задача популяризации – поиск новых участников, которые будут задавать по–настоящему интересные полезные вопросы, а в будущем, помогать коллегам ответами. К сожалению, я не обладают знаниями, которые бы позволили мне пригласить на сайт только людей, задающих исключительно качественные вопросы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не понимая, что является хорошим результатом, что превосходным, не имеет смысла цель ставить: одно дело 100-метровку до 10 секунд пробежать, а другое за 15. Хорошим критерием постановки цели является **выживание**: зависит ли выживание сайта от кол-ва просмотров?  Сколько этих просмотров необходимо?¶ О **миссии** ―больше не всегда лучше: дублирование неизбежно (не этот сайт так другой), но хорошо ли пытаться внимание русскоязычной аудитории от большого SO к ruSO тянуть? (150 знатоков на ruSO как раз ~3% от 5000 на SO, что ~трафику и вероятно больше чем на других SE сайтах)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky кстати, не только вы, но и никто не знает как решить проблему вечного сентября. Иначе бы SO вообще не был бы нужен. Практически всё на SO  направлено на повышение сигнал/шум в присутствии глобальной аудитории. Я не знаю примеров, которые бы с этой проблемой лучше SO справлялись бы

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky  Если *есть объективные причины полагать, что рост ruSO может улучшить интернет*, то в зависимости от конкретных причин можно рассмотреть различные меры, к примеру: временно открыть "floodgate": разрешить все темы, которые были разрешёнными в начале существования SO (посмотреть на самые популярные вопросы, которые либо [удалены](https://goo.gl/X7OhIC) либо [закрыты](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=closed%3ayes%20is%3aq%20)). Но *не зная глубину проблемы*: на 1% подвинуть результат или на 10000% процентов надо—предлагать меры по популяризации не очень полезно.

Answer (score 6):

Спешу предложить инициативу с публикацией вопросов наших товарищей и коллег на сайте.

**Предпосылки**

Я часто вижу, что мои товарищи задают огромное количество вопросов лично в реальной жизни, через личные сообщения в социальных сетях, чаты и т.д. Проблема в том, что все знания эти утрачиваются, а ответ находится далеко не всегда.

**Предлагаемое решение**

Если я вижу, что кто либо из моих коллег или товарищей публикует более или менее законченный вопрос (или вопрос, который я могу закончить самостоятельно) в соц. сетях, чатах и т. д. я буду публиковать такие вопросы на сайте. Как только вопрос получит ответ, я смогу опубликовать ссылку на него в ответ на исходное сообщение в соц. сети.

Comment: И как рядовой программист, который столкнулся с проблемой, поймёт, к какой категории отнести свой вопрос? Для меня, например, половина моих вопросов должна идти мастеру) так как он сразу ответит и скажет, где косяк. Другое дело, если у вопроса просмотров много, а ответа нет, тогда можно как то к мастеру подкинуть

Comment: @zayn1991 если эта проблема может возникнуть и у другого программиста, то задайте ваш вопрос на Stack Overflow. Сайт существует не для того чтобы лично вам помочь решить проблему (сайт не help desk). Stack Overflow существует, чтобы не приходилось каждому человеку каждый раз заново проблему решать—чтобы *помочь всем с тем же вопросом*. Если нашли решение (не важно где), то опубликуйте его как ответ: ваш вопрос/ответ может помочь кому-нибудь ещё (к примеру вам через полгода, когда детали забудутся), а вы можете получить отклик на решение/альтернативные решения/возможные обновления со временем.

Comment: Хорошая идея, только это точечные удары, таким методом можно брать вопрос в соц. сети (интересно, там часто такие вопросы публикуют?), гуглить ответ на enSO, постить вопрос и ответ на ruSO и давать ссылку.

Comment: @Other Как верно замечает Dmitriy Simushev, наша задача не в количестве, а в качестве. Представьте, если с помощью личных рекомендаций каждый из участников сможет пригласить хотя бы пару хороших коллег, которые будут задавать по одному хорошему вопросу, например, в неделю. Мне кажется, это того стоит!

Comment: Не в бровь, а в глаз. Вот только я прекрасно помню как я ратовал в чате за более-менее качественные вопросы, но выяснилось что тут важнее чтобы народ с гугла заходил, а не структурированные и качественные вопросы.

Comment: @Other не вы один бьетесь за качество ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, рад за это :)

Answer (score 3):

Можно завести группы/сообщества в соцсетях - FB, VK, еще где-нибудь, в ЖЖ, может быть. Публиковать (перепащивать - как это по-русски?) там иногда избранные вопросы с ответами, обсуждать всякие связанные с SO вопросы, привлекать людей к SO. Обсуждения в ЖЖ могут быть иногда и по формату удобнее, чем комменты в SO, в т. ч здесь, на Мете.

Comment: В [твиттере](https://twitter.com/rustackoverflow/) публикуются популярные сообщения. Насчет групп VK, FB не уверен, т.к. для дискуссий тут есть своя инфраструктура. Но вот размещать рекламу в упомянутых соцсетях вполне разумно.

Comment: "Перепащивать" = делать репосты.

Comment: Ну если Вы -- блоггер/известная_личность, пожалуйста, сделайте рекламу, донесите людям благую весть. Но с нуля поднимать группу/сообщество - это ещё тот труд, может стоит сразу SO продвигать, а не "группу по SO"?

Comment: Группа уже [есть](https://vk.com/stackoverflow). Ее развитие в планах. Как верно заметил @Other, пока не понятно как группа в соц. сетях решает проблему популяризации сообщества.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вполне очевидно решает, т.к. ссылку может увидеть человек, не имеющий аккаунта на SO, но зарегистрированный в соответствующей соц.сети.

Comment: @alexolut Угу. Я тоже это вижу примерно так, что вся информация, как и прежде, будет публиковаться на Мете, а в ВКонтакте ссылка. Социальные сети – отличное место для вынесения медиа. Например, фотографий со встреч сообщества!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, не то, чтобы я был удивлён, но 6 подписчиков? Да я большему количеству в реальности поведал о сайте. Может компания выделить деньги на продвижение группы?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, не знаю дату открытия группы, но как минимум с 14 числа. Сейчас 24. Выходит 10 дней. 10! = 3628800. Более 3-х с половиной миллионов за десять дней?

Answer (score 3):

Почему бы не устраивать конкурсы с наградами от компании?
Подарки в России любят особо сильно, так что такой магнит может хорошо притянуть известность.
Например, код-гольфы. Или на самый интересный ответ хорошего вопроса (этим вопросом наверняка бы поделились в этих ваших социалках :)). Или авторский дизайн лого, который будет как дудл висеть на главной (временно, конечно). Или... Вариантов много.

Comment: За победу в код-гольфах дарить гольфы (это как носки, только длиннее). =)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да Вы остряк от Бога, сэр! А гольфы у меня есть, знаю что это.

Comment: На всякий случай напомнил, вдруг кто-то забыл. )

Answer (score 2):

Может создать что то типа песочницы для вопросов. Там его (вопрос) дооформить и причесать как положено, а затем отправить в "профи".

Или несколько разделов предусмотреть типа начальный, средний и мастер.

Comment: Тут речь о PR. Менять формат самого so для привлечения аудитории - из области фантастики, как мне кажется.

Comment: По задумке, в ней не должно быть необходимости. Если вопрос требует дооформления, он закрывается (первое время с пометкой *[требует правки]*), дооформляется и переоткрывается обратно. А если не дооформляется или дооформляется недостаточно, то не переоткрывается.

Comment: Я тоже ощущаю необходимость стратификации вопросов по уровню - хотя бы три уровня - новичок, средний, профи. Понятно, что формат сайта  изменить маловероятно, но может быть, соотв. тэги могли бы помочь? Желательно только, чтобы эти тэги (beginner/intermediate/prof) навешивал не автор вопроса, а более-менее искушенные участники.

Comment: Неясно что даст деление по кастам. Да и разницу невозможно точно поставить.

Comment: @Other - оно и сейчас есть - но когда будет явно, то хоть понятно куда обращаться

Comment: @Other, "Неясно что даст деление по кастам" -- я говорил не о делении людей по кастам, а о делении вопросов по уровню. Это может повысить эффективность. Это даст возможность каждому участнику просматривать/искать вопросы и ответы своего уровня, не тратя время: для начинающих - на безнадёжные попытки понять "китайскую грамоту"; для экспертов -  на просмотр сотен вопросов уровня "А это чё тут в скобках" или "мне задали прибавить два к трем, а я не знаю как".

Comment: Нету тут такого. Да, допустим, пользователя @VladD не определишь в джуны, скорее сениоры, но большинство весьма трудно однозначно определить в группу, к примеру:  тот же Влад профи в шарпе, но в вебе ещё тот джун :) Поэтому существующее деление по знакам (есть знаки за метки).

Comment: @m.vokhm, это было бы неплохо, но кто будет классифицировать ВСЕ вопросы? Сами авторы почти всегда очень... необразованны в правилах (лень читать онные?), куда там знать об этикете и грамотном выборе качества своего вопроса (каждый выберет что его вопрос уровня сениора и выше, чтобы увеличить шанс на решение от профи); завсегдатаи не могут грамотно оценить любой вопрос, да и кому надо делать лишнюю работу, особенно если вспомнить что в проверках мы и так разбираем мусор.

Comment: @Other, ну тут же всё (или почти всё) делается усилиями энтузиастов, в меру их желания и возможности. Сделать метки Beginner, Intermediate, Profi (ну или по-другому как-то назвать), и дать право навешивать эти метки тем, у кого репутация, например, 5000+. Я думаю, люди здесь в большинстве своем взрослые и добросовестные, и будут их ставить в тех областях, в которых разбираются, и не будут в тех, в которых не разбираются. Ведь нетрудно отличить вопрос новичка от вопроса профи - с первого взгляда видно, порой даже в суть вопроса вникать не надо,  и метку поставить не тяжело.

Comment: @m.vokhm, на практике это никому не нужно и сложнореализуемо. Ведь даже неясно зачем это и чем это поможет.

Answer (score 2):

Можно публиковать дайджест красивых и полезных решений в популярных профильных сообществах. Например, можно писать на [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru).

Comment: Отличная идея! Будет здорово, если вы готовы взяться за реализацию!

Comment: Я планирую, но пока с отсылом к "своим" темам на SO Docs ([раз](stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/4087), [два](stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1395), [три](stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/8005)). К сожалению, пока не вижу большого количества красивых решений на языке `R` в русскоязычном разделе.

Можно еще подумать насчет свого аналога [Документации](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation)

Comment: @ikashnitsky свой аналог Документации вроде бы у нас будет, но не раньше чем основная Документация выйдет из периода открытой беты.

Comment: На Хабр? [Николаса уже забанили без объяснение причин](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42249424#42249424), но предположительно за саморекламу (последнее сообщение в его [профиле](https://web.archive.org/web/20150110235953/http://habrahabr.ru:80/users/devexpert/topics/) — смена лицензии Хэшкода). Не надо наступать на те же грабли.