# Публичная страница сообщества в ВКонтакте

Tags: обсуждение, вехи, вконтакте

Спешу предложить принять участие в создании и ведении публичной страницы Stack Overflow на сайте ВКонтакте.

Основная цель публичной страницы – привлечь внимание людей, которые все еще используют старые phpBB-форумы. Показать им, что в Рунете (и в Интернете, в общем) существуют достойные внимания сообщества профессиональных разработчиков, готовых помочь своим коллегам в сложную минуту.

Адрес публичной страницы: https://vk.com/stackoverflow

#### Предыстория

Я провел небольшое исследование на предмет возможности того, чтобы кто–то вел страничку сообщества для нас с вами. Выводы: это невозможно. Все, с кем я пытался работать над страничкой, не понимали идеологии и принципов организации сообщества. Они то и дело норовили опубликовать едкую шутку или отсканированные книги. Как мне кажется, это совершенно не то, что нам надо.

#### Что ожидается от публичной страницы сообщества?

*Увидеть информацию о Вас!* Именно мы, участники, и есть «Stack Overflow». Публичная страница должна рассказывать о нас!

#### Зачем вообще нужна публичная страница?

Изначальная цель данного мероприятия – показать, что быстрое решение профессиональных вопросов по программированию в Рунете действительно возможно.

Как мне кажется, все еще существует люди, которые скептически относятся к публикации вопросов в Интернете, держа в уме предыдущий опыт общения на интернет–форумах. Глядя на наш личный пример, пример реальных людей, которые, возможно, работают с ними в одной компании, и то прекрасное, что мы создаем, с большой вероятностью, наши коллеги поменяют свое мнение в лучшую сторону.

#### Какие есть предложения?

На мой взгляд, было бы здорово рассказать пользователям сайта ВКонтакте о нас и культуре нашего сообщества. Подходящими публикациями будут:

- [Интересные вопросы и ответы по программированию, как на русском, так и на английском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4072/).
- Любые публикации по программированию сделанные участниками сообщества на любом другом ресурсе.
- Интересные факты о вас, как людях, о ваших компаниях, где вы работаете, продуктах, над которыми работаете, хобби, которыми занимаетесь по вечерам, встречах и т. д.
- Интересные или смешные комментарии из чата.
- Другие интересные на ваш взгляд материалы, которые как–либо связаны с вами или сообществом.

Для того чтобы разместить новость, вопрос или интересную информацию, просто используйте ссылку «Предложить новость» на странице группы в ВКонтакте. Пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить ее меткой `#stackoverflow`.

Если вы считаете, что следует расширить или сузить тематику публикаций, или как–либо иначе изменить подход к публичной странице, пожалуйста, дайте знать.

Буду рад улучшить нашу общую страничку согласно пожеланиям сообщества! С нетерпением ждем ваших публикаций в ВКонтакте!

**Обновление**

Для того, чтобы любой участник сообщества мог предложить содержимое для размещения на публичной странице, мы создали чат: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70437/vk-com-stackoverflow. Если вы хотите что–то опубликовать от имени группы на ВКонтакте, оставить отзыв о содержимом группы, высказать свои идеи по теме, либо обсудить саму группу, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь использовать этот чат!

Comment: _Интересные или смешные комментарии из чата._ - хе хе

Comment: Почему `Stack Overflow`? Почему не сказано что это именно русское ответвление?

Comment: @Other Вы имеете в виду в группе?

Comment: Да, в шапке....

Comment: Можно гольфы туда постить. Это же, обычно, хорошая вещь в плане демонстрации мощи компутера.

Comment: @Other Как мне кажется, в этом нет большого смысла (если ошибаюсь, пожалуйста, поправьте). В моем представлении, SO – это один большой проект, который сейчас не до конца правильно разработан с инфраструктурной точки зрения, в контексте разделения на языки. То есть если «Stack Overflow на английском» имеет право быть упомянут как «Stack Overflow», то русскоязычное сообщество может быть упомянуто без ссылки на язык на тех же правах.

Comment: @Other Буду рад увидеть ваши вопросы–соревнования в новостях!

Comment: Разумеется. Просто подумал что люди могут побоятся что сайт не русский.

Comment: Придумать бы эти соревнования...

Comment: @Other Можно конкурс провести на лучшее соревнование! :)

Comment: Если придумать достойный гольф не могут даже участники, то что говорить о тех, кто только может заинтересоваться SO. Кстати да, можно туда справку по терминалогии SO/IT написать, в картинках сразу описать правила сайта и поведение хорошего тона, особенности работы, которые здесь передаются "из уст в уста". Меня в ВК нет, поэтому постить не могу (или даже если бы был не смог?).

Comment: @Other Идея в том, чтобы размещать публикации в группе именно от участников сообщества. Если бы была, смогли бы. Если хотите что–либо опубликовать, но у вас нет учетной записи на ВКонтакте, опубликуйте в ответ к этому вопросу, я перенесу все в ВКонтакте.

Comment: Конкурс на графическое изображение Генерала Диса Куссия

Comment: Добавляйте к записям тематические метки #c++ #html помимо основного #stackoverflow.

Comment: _"То есть если «Stack Overflow на английском» имеет право быть упомянут как «Stack Overflow»"_ - для него это не важно. А мы хотим подчеркнуть, что речь о русскоязычном сообществе. Т. е. от убирания этого мы теряем, а не получаем, хотя в части, что "имеем право", я полностью согласен.

Comment: Раз уж зашла речь про ВК, может как-то надо добавить её в список соц.сетей по ссылке `поделиться` под сообщением?

Comment: `Спешу предложить принять участие в создании и ведении публичной страницы Stack Overflow на сайте ВКонтакте.
Основная цель публичной страницы – привлечь внимание людей, которые все еще используют старые phpBB-форумы.` Не понимаю как связано одно с другим.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper Все очень просто. а) Публичную страницу, если она нужна, лучше вести всем сообществом. б) Есть вероятность, что те, кто используют ВКонтакте, не используют Stack Overflow. Идея – до них достучаться, объединив а и б.

Comment: Давно бы надо, я не понимаю, почему ее нет) Завели бы группу, постили бы новости, интересные вопросы, получили бы галочку верификации...

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky безусловно. Но связи со старыми phpBB-форумами тут нет. Вы написали, что `Основная цель публичной страницы – привлечь внимание людей, которые все еще используют старые phpBB-форумы` а не `Основная цель публичной страницы – привлечь внимание людей, кто используют ВКонтакте, не используют Stack Overflow`

Comment: @Flippy -- что значит "ее нет" -- а это что: https://vk.com/stackoverflow

Comment: Только непонятно, почему там с 10 января ни одной записи не появилось....

Comment: Раз на то пошло - лучше уж и канал/группу в Телеграмм. Я думаю - это более удобно для любого программиста, нежели Вк...

Comment: @azhirov1991 Да, возможно. Думаю над форматом. Просто чат – не интересно, так как у нас есть прекрасная система чатов. Подскажите, как вы видите формат канала в Telegram?

Comment: Сделать канал + группу. Канал с решениями для вопросов из Stackoverflow, с грамотными решениями вопросов, а группу для обсуждения ответов. Можно сделать даже 2 группы в связке - для неопытных пользователей, где могут помочь более опытные ребята, и для опытных, где можно разобрать более сложные вопросы.

Comment: @azhirov1991 Спасибо! Подумаю над вашей идеей. Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем для обсуждения вопросов не подходит существующая система чатов?

Comment: Я наверное не встречал ещё подобные группы в телеграмм) Отталкиваюсь от того, что есть у меня)

Comment: @azhirov1991 Понял! Спасибо!

Comment: "Интересные или смешные комментарии" Когда я это делал, вы попросили удалить эти картинки =/

Comment: @Suvitruf Смешные != высмеивающие.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky кого, если имена замазаны?

Comment: @Suvitruf  Вы о чем?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky в картинке нет имён, просто забавные обезличенные вопросы от случайных пользователей. Скорей всего, от троллей. Не понимаю, кого это может обидеть.

Comment: @Suvitruf «Забавными» они показались не всем, мне написали подписчики группы и пожаловались на публикуемое содержимое. И, к слову, подскажите, пожалуйста, заче вы спрашиваете этот на Мете в комментариях, если мы обсуждали эту проблему развернуто в личных сообщениях с вами, причем, уже довольно давно?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да я случайно сейчас просто наткнулся на этот пост и решил тут написать сразу. Можете удалить комментарии, если хотите.