# Выборы модераторов группы сообщества на сайте ВКонтакте

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, выборы, вконтакте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Многие знают, что у сообщества есть [публичная страница ВКонтакте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4759/6), основная цель которой — рассказать внешнему миру о нас, сообществе, чем мы живем день ото дня,  о том, что нас волнует, что нам интересно, а также пролить чуть–чуть света на компанию–разработчика.

Как мне кажется, настало время полностью передать ведение группы в руки сообщества, так как ни один нанятый специалист с задачей не справился, а лично мне задача оказалась не по силам. В связи с этим предлагаю нам выбрать двух действующих участников сообщества, которые бы хотели выступить в роли «представителей сообщества» на сайте ВКонтакте. Будущим избранникам предстоит, руководствуясь своими знаниями и [отзывами коллег](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70437/vk-com-stackoverflow), определить, что будет публиковаться на нашей странице ВКонтакте.

Если вы хотите и можете стать представителем сообщества Stack Overflow во ВКонтакте, пожалуйста, опубликуйте ответ к этому вопросу. В ответе в двух словах расскажите о себе, почему вам интересно быть представителем сообщества и несколько слов о наличии или отсутствии подобного опыта ранее.

#### Кого мы ищем?

К кандидатам, по сути, всего несколько базовых требований:

- Будущий представитель сообщества должен иметь более 1 000 баллов репутации на Stack Overflow на русском.
- Иметь достаточно свободного времени, чтобы делать минимум две публикации в неделю.
- Быть социальным (как минимум иметь страницу на сайте ВКонтакте) и понимать, как примерно работают социальные сети.
- Любить сообщество Stack Overflow и крайне позитивно относиться к коллегам.

#### Условия успешного выбора

Выборы будут считаться состоявшимися, если:

- Один из кандидатов будет иметь минимум три голоса «за».
- Количество положительных голосов будет превышать количество отрицательных.

Выборы будут продолжаться до момента, пока мы не выберем двух представителей сообщества. Участник будет считаться выбранным, как только он(а) будет соответствовать вышеупомянутым критериям, но не раньше 20–го января 2018 года.

Пожалуйста, предложите вашу кандидатуру, если вы любите социальные сети, ответственны и готовы стать голосом сообщества Stack Overflow на сайте ВКонтакте!

С нетерпением ждем ваших откликов и голосов!

---

Для обсуждения идей ведения группы, её содержимого и любых других аспектов, связанных с нашим «представительством» на сайте ВКонтакте, пожалуйста, используйте чат: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70437/vk-com-stackoverflow.

Comment: "чтобы делать минимум две публикации в неделю" Что под публикацией подразумевается?

Comment: @Suvitruf Пост от имени группы. Например: https://vk.com/stackoverflow?w=wall-33558403_184 Если «это» называется как–то по–другому, пожалуйста, подскажите, как именно? Я поправлю текст вопроса. (Или внесите улучшающую правку самостоятельно, за что я буду крайне признателен.)

Comment: Просто одно дело - небольшая заметка, но совсем другое, если пост что-то типо "даджест топовых вопросов за неделю". Я к тому, что некоторые посты можно за пару минут накидать, а на какие-то и часа не хватит.

Comment: @Suvitruf Мне кажется, это можно оставить на усмотрение модераторов группы и «запросов» сообщества в чате. Если времени/желания/умения не хватает, то не вижу смысла делать подобные публикации. Главная цель группы — рассказывать о сообществе внешнему миру. Уверен, это можно сделать огромным количеством способов. Какой выбрать — зависит только от самих представителей.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ищите человека с опытом раскрутки/поддержки групп, среди разработчиков таковых единицы (если вообще есть), но, думаю, они найдутся.

Comment: @DaemonHK Спасибо за совет! Мне кажется, нам не нужна какая–то раскрутка. О существовании Stack Overflow, думаю, догадываются многие. Наша задача, скорее, показать, что это не просто сайт с ответами, но то, что за этими советами стоят реальные прекрасные люди. Акцент именно на людях. Мы ищем энтузиастов, которые понимают, что такое Stack Overflow и готовы делиться информацией о сообществе в соц. сетях.

Comment: Изредка писать посты, возможно иногда даже дайджесты лучших вопросов я бы мог взяться. Продвигать группу - нет.

Comment: @Suvitruf Пожалуйста, выдвигайте вашу кандидатуру! :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky кстати, раз на данном ресурсе по сути просто негде выкладывать гайды, может в ВК делать подборки из вопросов по разным стекам, которые будут затрагивать и разъяснять основные моменты? Но тогда вопросы, попавшие в подборку, нужно будет защитить от редактирования/удаления.

Comment: @DaemonHK Не могли бы вы пояснить вашу мысль более развернуто, так как [инициатива для руководств у на есть](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6420/6)!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Это я видел, даже проголосовал "за", только нет отчетности никакой, чего добились, как потом такие посты искать? Я о говорил о некой сборной солянке, например, возьмем AJAX, "отправка формы, средствами php и ajax", "ajax-пагинация", "ajax-подгрузка контента". Собираются лучшие вопросы и выкладываются в группе. Кстати, а что с иницитивой "Книга сообщества" то в итоге?

Comment: Первое, что нужно сделать: обновить фотоматрицу.

Comment: Что-то нет энтузиастов совсем =/

Comment: @Suvitruf Ничего страшного! Ещё целый месяц впереди!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky в принципе да, сейчас ещё праздники в тому же и т.п.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky может стоит понизить планку в 1к, а то она выше даже чем для модераторов сообщества получается.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, не надо — кандидат должен быть уже освоившимся в сообществе. А касательно модераторов — тот порог чисто формален, а у самих голосующих планка для кандидатов значительно выше.

Comment: Извиняюсь за вопрос, но всё-же. Какое-то материальное вознаграждение планируется, или это полностью на добровольческих началах? Вопрос этот взялся из того что такая работа это большой или огромный вклад личного времени и энергий.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Нет, не планируется. Я убежден, что то, что многие сделают без материального вознаграждения, никогда бы не стали делать за деньги. Пример тому модерация сайта. Например, у Джоэла [значится 90 проверок](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky?tab=activity&sort=reviews). Уверяю, что вы не за какие деньги не наймете его проверять ваши тексты, но за бесплатно, если вы публикуете информацию для сообщества, он готов помочь в оформлении. Таких примеров — весь Stack Overflow. Публичная страничка — лишь возможность рассказать «внешнему миру» о нас, о наших идеях и целях.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Ведение группы не должно (и, уверен, не будет) отнимать много времени. Если будущий модератор публичной странички проводит какое–то время на сайте, все, что требуется — опубликовать интересный вопрос с основного сайта или Меты в публичной странице, добавив метку #stackoverflow и комментарий из одного предложения (посмотрите, пожалуйста, как это делается сейчас). Никто кроме нас самих, разработчиков, не скажет, какой вопрос интересный, а какой — нет.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Что еще очень важно: у нас был робот, который публиковал сообщения в твиттер. Но лично мне кажется, что лучше совсем без соц сетей, если это делается «потому что так делают все» и «дешево». Если мы хотим рассказать о нас, мы это сделаем сами, с душой, без роботов и «SMM», простым человеческим языком. Рассказывать будем лишь тогда, когда захотим, в том объеме, в котором нам покажется необходимым, публиковать будем лишь то, что сочтет нужным сообщество.

Comment: без обязаловки, а когда самому хочется это уже другое дело

Comment: неужели больше ни у кого из 100k юзеров нет времени/желания ?

Comment: @Alex Возможно, есть и желание и время, но нет умений (например, как у меня).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Не то чтобы у меня было много свободного времени, но, думаю, пару постов в неделю в группе я бы мог делать.

Может буду постить там дайджесты интересных вопросов, переводить новости с блога SO и т.п.

P.S. отписался тут только потому что никто не проявил больше инициативы, а помочь хочется. Если найдётся более заинтересованный человек с уймой свободного времени, то удалю ответ.

Comment: `переводить новости с блога SO` это было бы вообще супер