# В блоке "Важное на мете" находятся "неважные" вопросы

Tags: дефект, мета

Есть вопрос [Выборы модераторов группы сообщества на сайте ВКонтакте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6590/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%92%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5?cb=1)

Сейчас он расположен в блоке "Важное на мете":

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в тоже время у него нет метки "важное":

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это "жук" или так задумано?