# Есть ли чат и телеграм-канал SO?

Tags: поддержка

Есть ли чат и телеграм-канал SO?

Comment: чат есть на https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462 ... не думаю, что если бы чат был в телеграмме активность была бы выше

Comment: @МихаилРебров если бы он был официальным, то, имхо, активность была бы выше (всё же в телеге удобнее, симпатичнее и динамичнее, чем в SE-чате). Правда для модерации пришлось бы отдельные схемы задействовать, как минимум.

Comment: нет и не надо...

Answer (score 5):

На текущий момент никаких Telegram сущностей у SO нет. [Поиск по MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=telegram) возвращает вовсе 0 результатов по слову "telegram".

Официальные доступные ресурсы на внешних социальных платформах указаны в подвале страницы. Сейчас это: Facebook, Твиттер, LinkedIn и Instagram.

Есть ещё полуофициальная [страница Вконтакте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4759/176217) (спасибо [Кириллу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/235436/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2) за подсказку) именно для ruSO. Кстати, под анонсом той страницы как раз был "ответ" (ныне преобразован в [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4759/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5#comment17278_4759)) следующего содержания:

> Раз на то пошло - лучше уж и канал/группу в Телеграмм. Я думаю - это более удобно для любого программиста, нежели Вк...

Так что уже более трёх лет назад предложение высказывалось.

Comment: Ещё vk.com/stackoverflow

Comment: @КириллМалышев добавил в пост.

Answer (score 0):

Не встречал. Скорее всего, нет.