# Поддержка профессиональных конференций

Tags: поддержка, faq

<sub>Свободный перевод публикации из блога «[Supporting Community Conferences](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/)» [@Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=profile).</sub>

---

Существует интересный способ [популяризации сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4072/): узнать, какие предстоящие **конференции, семинары, встречи, мероприятия или собрания** могут быть интересны сообществу и какие из них позволят привлечь новых сильных участников, которые влюблены в профессию не меньше, чем мы!

Есть множество способов, с помощью которых команда развития сообществ может оказать поддержку вашим начинаниям в данном направлении; к настоящему моменту мы пробовали следующие подходы.

### Листовки

Простой способ продвижения сообщества — раздача заинтересованным людям на мероприятиях одностраничных цветных листовок. Мы уже подготовили несколько вариантов листовок как для сайтов прошедших аттестацию, так и для бета-сайтов.

[image]

### Наклейки и футболки

Рады предложить любую сувенирную продукцию Stack Exchange, необходимую вам для проведения мероприятия. Мы стараемся подготовить уникальные индивидуальные сувениры для каждого сайта Stack Exchange (которые, к примеру, время от времени получают лучшие участники каждого из сообществ).

[image]

Вероятно, если вы решите продвигать свое сообщество Stack Exchange на каком-либо мероприятии, вам захочется получить сувенирную продукцию с символикой вашего сайта! Мы *пока* не создали сувениры для каждого сайта Stack Exchange, но мы идем к этому — вы можете [просмотреть все вопросы с тегом «сувенирная продукция» на Мете](http://stackexchange.com/filters/18811/meta-swag?sort=newest) и проверить, что уже создано на данный момент.

### Визитные карточки

Мы начали делать индивидуальные визитные карточки для каждого сайта Stack Exchange. О появлении визиток для конкретного сообщества мы [публикуем информацию на Мете](http://stackexchange.com/filters/18817/meta-bizcards). Изначально, визитные карточки задуманы не *только* для модераторов сообществ, но если вы хотите продвигать ваше сообщество на каком–либо мероприятии и считаете, что раздача визитных карточек это то, что вам нужно — дайте нам знать, и мы изготовим их для вас.

[image]

### Финансовая поддержка мероприятий

Мы официально уже выступали спонсорами несколько мероприятий, что не только дало нам возможность помочь в популяризации ваших сообществ, но и позволило официально сообщить присутствующим о том, что в Интернете есть такие фантастические сайты вопросов и ответов с уникально высоким соотношением «сигнал/шум».

[image]

Будем рады предоставить логотип любого сайта в высоком разрешении для его размещения в программе мероприятия. Мы создали [специальную страницу с логотипами](http://stackexchange.com/about/logos). Если вам нужны какие-либо другие графические материалы к сайтам, просто разместите вопрос на Мете, и мы с удовольствием предоставим их вам!

### Членство в комитетах

В некоторых случаях есть возможность стать членом комитетов, которые могут быть интересны и полезны сообществу:

- [Хотим ли мы, чтобы Stack Exchange стала коллективным членом TeX User Group?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/do-we-want-stackexchange-to-become-an-institutional-member-of-the-tug)
- [Финансирование конференции OWASP](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/374/owasp-conference-sponsorship)
- [Бесплатное членство в Лиге профессиональных системных администраторов](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1558/free-lopsa-memberships)

Мы счастливы объединять людей в группы для поддержки деятельности этих ключевых организаций, компенсируя при необходимости членские взносы лучших участников. Обсудите это на Мете вашего сообщества, чтобы определить, какой вариант, по вашему мнению, является наилучшим, и мы сделаем все возможное, чтобы реализовать его.

### Финансовая поддержка участия в мероприятиях для лидеров сообществ

В зависимости от обстоятельств и места проведения, мы также можем оказывать поддержку лидерам сообществ для их *участия* в мероприятиях от имени своего сайта. В разумных пределах мы покрываем ваши расходы на участие и обеспечим вас большим количеством сувенирной продукции, которая поможет вам, когда вы будете представлять себя на мероприятии и знакомиться с другими его участниками. Нет, правда! Мы уже [реализовали это с тремя лидерами сообществ из GIS, GameDev и Security](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/community-conference-sponsorships/) — и нам бы хотелось продолжить такую практику!

В ответ мы ожидаем от вас, что в своем блоге или на соответствующей Мете сайта вы подробно опишете основные впечатления и опыт, полученные на конференции, так, чтобы другие участники сообщества могли хотя бы виртуально принять участие в ней. Не нужно писать много, достаточно хотя бы 4-5 абзацев, описывающих, что крутого вы узнали и особенно интересного увидели, упомянув оказанную спонсорскую поддержку.

Также, если в ходе конференции вы услышите какие-либо вопросы (в том числе не заданные напрямую), которые стоят того, чтобы оказаться на вашем сайте, не стесняйтесь *опубликовать их!* Вы можете [помогать экспертам получить ответы на их вопросы](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/) или даже [задать вопрос и самостоятельно ответить на него](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Вне зависимости от того, что интересует и вдохновляет вас на мероприятии, попытайтесь сделать из такого вопроса небольшой общедоступный «артефакт», из которого сообщество может узнать что-то новое и извлечь пользу.

В любом случае не перенапрягайтесь — наслаждайтесь мероприятием, попутно рассказывая собравшимся о вашем сообществе.

### Финансовая поддержка выступлений лидеров сообществ

А теперь более серьезная просьба — если вы чувствуете в себе силы *выступить* на мероприятии от имени вашего сообщества, мы готовы сделать все возможное, чтобы помочь вам реализовать это желание. Мы называем эту программу «Бюро докладчиков», [мы уже публиковали информацию об этом на некоторых основных Метах](http://stackexchange.com/filters/18816/meta-speakers-bureau).

В рамках программы «Бюро докладчиков» мы компенсируем следующие расходы (если их не компенсируют организаторы конференций):

1. Билет на мероприятие;
2. Проживание в отеле во все дни мероприятия;
3. Транспортные расходы;
4. Суточные.

От вас требуется, чтобы ваше выступление имело такой же эффект, как огромный логотип Stack Exchange. (Кстати, хорошо бы еще на лицо нанести аквагрим с символикой Stack Exchange.) Если серьезно, главная цель бюро докладчиков — дать вам возможность *продемонстрировать свою компетентность* в соответствующей области. Обучать коллег и учиться у них – наша основная задача, выступление на мероприятии является прямым следствием этого.

### С чего начать?

Недостаточно просто написать в Мете «мы должны отправить кого-нибудь на конференцию» и ждать, пока кто-то согласится. Хотя существует чрезвычайно успешный опыт поддержки выступлений на конференциях, большинство идей не прошли дальше стадии предложения. Пожалуйста, учтите следующие рекомендации:

1. **Первый шаг — публикация в Мете**. Вы можете начать обсуждение на Мете, чтобы определить, какие конференции, семинары, встречи, мероприятия и собрания могут быть интересны вашему сообществу, и на каких из них можно было бы рассказать, насколько крутое ваше сообщество, людям, которым оно может понравиться не меньше, чем вам, но которые, вероятно, никогда не слышали о вашем сайте (или вообще о Stack Exchange).
2. **Провести небольшое исследование**. О чем эта конференция? Когда она пройдет? Сколько человек примут участие в ней? Каковы расходы на участие в ней? Какие возможности предоставляются на конференции для того, чтобы выступить, раздать сувенирную продукцию и другими способами привлечь внимание к вашему сайту?
3. **Добиться поддержки**. Расскажите сообществу о своих идеях. Объясните всем, почему «это хорошая идея, мы должны сделать это!». Будьте по-настоящему конкретными и убедительными, удостоверьтесь, что поощряете обратную связь и идеи. Мы будем учитывать обсуждения на Мете при принятии решения о том, какие конференции и какая деятельность могут дать результат.
4. **Привлеките наше внимание к вопросу**. Если ваше предложение получило поддержку сообщества, свяжитесь с нами и расскажите подробнее о мероприятии и его участниках, отправив письмо на адрес community@stackexchange.com. Только от вас зависит, удастся ли вам убедить нас в реализации самых лучших ваших идей. Чем больше подробной информации вы предоставите, тем больше шансов, что мы сможем стать спонсорами вашего сообщества и оказать какую бы то ни было необходимую поддержку для максимально успешного участия в мероприятии.

И, пожалуйста, не забудьте рассказать нам о вариантах финансирования участия в конференции *заблаговременно* до времени проведения мероприятия. Конечно, можно попробовать организовать все в последнюю минуту, но мы вряд ли сможем сделать что-то существенное в условиях дефицита времени.

Если предстоит какое-либо мероприятие, которое может быть интересно вашему сообществу, расскажите об этом на вашей Мете, держа в уме вышеописанный алгоритм, и посмотрите, что получится — мы вам поможем!

Comment: Радует что поддержка возможна. Кто будет представлять компанию у нас в России или СНГ?

Comment: Кому будет интересно ПЛАТИТЬ за то, чтобы послушать местный контингент :) Не в обиду, но правда, ведь здесь вряд ли кто-то есть кто работал над проектами росскосмоса или делал игры подобные diablo. Да тут даже чуваки из яндекса и гугла то уже врят ли сидят, откуда у них время. И вот тогда вопрос сам напрашивается - а кто будет выступать? Да тут есть умные, в плане "я могу удивить человека который три дня назад книгу прочел", но по факту они могут пересказать лишь "мусор" подобранный с англоязычного сегмента, а на вопросы "почему оно так" не смогут дать ответа, так как они и сами-то не знают.

Comment: Пусть потенциальные выступающие-учителя лучше время на самосовершенствование потратят чем на загрязнение ума остальным.

Comment: @OlmerDale у меня складывается ощущение, что ты думаешь на SO все участники - твои одноклассники из 10-го В......Но нет, представители вышеприведенных (и не только) организаций присутствуют. Просто лично тебе не докладывают.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я сужу то как представители участвуют в жизни ресурса. Если судить по вэб направлению, то представители росскомоса не могут осилить что-либо сложнее jQ, так как по тегам с jQ они всегда отвечают, а вот react + angular2 нет. Это означает лишь то что время у них есть, ведь по jQ они отвечают! Остается лишь то что с другим они не знакомы. Но я говорю только за вэб. Возможно на c, java и c# здесь действительно сильные специалисты, но я не уверен что прям того уровня, которые достойны учить других людей.

Comment: Для примера я несколько раз видел как участники с очень большим рейтингом своими ответами противоречат самым популярным книгам, с которыми я соглашался не просто после прочтения, а на практике. 

Я очень часто замечаю как самые активные участники отвечают на вопросы вообще не разбираясь в теме. Или что люди которые учат других сами не пишут, а лишь годами и годами собирают материал из офф тутеров и на их примере пишут хеловорлд. Вот такие будут учить на конференциях за деньги?

Comment: И я не хочу сказать что они глупые, я сам совсем не далеко ушел-отстал от них. Дело в том что лично я бы не хотел чтобы меня учил такой человек. А разве я могу желать другим что не хочу сам?

Comment: И самое главное является ли незримое присутствие желаемых гарантом того что именно они и будут выступать и говорить не о новых технологиях которые они конечно же не используют, ведь только дурак будет использовать новое, а о настоящих проблемах которые встречаются в настоящем мире?

Comment: Среди участников с первой страницы (top 36) есть 5-6 человек, чьи доклады (если бы они существовали) на конференции я бы с интересом послушал.